# Inequality Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

If $y(x)$ is a function which satisfies the following equation :
\begin{equation*}
y(x)=1+2\int_{0}^{x}u^{3}y(u)du
\end{equation*}
then could it be true that $y(\sqrt{2})<4?$

Comment: Have you tried using the Leibniz rule for differentiating under the integral?? I think it might help...

Comment: Have you seen the answer here?

Comment: I'm curious - can you answer this question without the Leibniz rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y(x)=1+2\int_{0}^{x} u^3 y(u) du, \implies y(0)=1.$$
Differentiate with respect to $x$  on both sides using Lebnitz Rule, to get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x^3 y(x) \implies \int \frac{dy}{y}=\int 2 x^3 dx+C$$
$$\implies \ln y= \frac{x^4}{2}+C \implies C=0$$
$$\implies y(x)=e^{\frac{x^4}{2}} \implies y(\sqrt{2})=e^{2} >4$$